# Haskell Error - "lacks an accompanying binding"

Tags: haskell

I have the following haskell code dealing with adding polynomials:

```
module PolyLA2 where  -- defines the module name so you can import from another haskell file

type Coeff = Int
type Exp = Int
type Polynomial = [(Coeff, Exp)] -- a list of terms in a polynomial formula

addpoly::Polynomial -> Polynomial -> Polynomial
addPoly [] ys = ys -- Base case 
addPoly xs [] = xs -- Base case 
addPoly ((a,b):xs) ((c,d):ys)
     | a == c = ((a, b + d) : (addPoly xs ys))
     | a < c = ((a,b) : (addPoly xs ((c,d) : ys)))
     | a > c = ((c,d) : (addPoly ((a,b) : xs) ys))
```

I believe the logic is correct however, when I try to compile it I get a "lacks accompany binding error" My question is what is causing this error?

Comment: Case: `addpoly` is not the same as `addPoly`

Comment: Wow, stupid mistake forgot to capitalize the p in 'addPoly'. Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you realize that you have redundant parentheses on every right-hand side? Also, you may be better off with a stricter `Polynomial` type and/or a more polymorphic one.

Answer (score 5):

The line:

```
addpoly::Polynomial -> Polynomial -> Polynomial
```

Should be:

```
addPoly::Polynomial -> Polynomial -> Polynomial
```

Notice the letter `P`.